# Fastest way to load into SQL table in Azure Databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

What is the fastest and the most efficient way to load into a SQL table from an Azure Databricks notebook?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to load data into SQL is using **partition tables** and **column-stored indexes**.

You can find a sample repro guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sql-db-databricks/azure-sql-db-databricks/).